# salesforce Trigger using how to insert/Update "Order" Record

Tags: trigger

In Salesforce `Order` Object Having Account Name, Contract Number filled. How to get those 2 records from salesforce Trigger, and How to Update the `Order.Status = 'Activate'`

Comment: Share your code whatever you have tried so far

Comment: @Santanu Boral actually i don't wrote any triiger just thinking about the process its poosbile or not
 if its possible how to write a Triiger above fields using...

Answer (score 1):

You can write a "before" trigger where you can fill in one field depending on values in other fields like this with the result being saved automatically:

```
trigger OrderTrigger on Order (before insert, before update) {
    for (Order o : Trigger.new) {
        if (String.isEmpty(o.Status)) {
            if (o.AccountId != null && o.ContractId != null) {
                o.Status = 'Active';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The fields are referenced by their "API Names" that can sometimes be a bit hard to find.

(Haven't tested this and you will also need to write unit test for it.)

Comment: Hi  @Keith C,  i tried this way, but order status is Not Updated to "Activaed",  it is still in Draft.

Comment: @user33433 Use `System.debug`calls to check that the `o.Status = 'Active';` line does run and fix if it doesn't. If it does run then some other `Order` related logic may be involved and I don't know what the solution would be in that case.

Comment: When i Create a Order, The Order Status is = Draft, its working Fine, Then after I insert a Order Item in Order That time The Order Status is Updated. like Status is Activated/submitted. by using Trigger.

Comment: Hi To All ,
I have New Scenario, i Create a One Order, the Order Status is Draft, and i Update the status of the Order as Submitted. But When i Update the Status of the Order as Submitted that time i get the Emil will be 2 times. how to solve this issue. please give me suggestions to me..